# On clicking Select component in Formik-Material-UI, app bar color is changing

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, material-design, formik, formik-material-ui

I am making a web project using [React](https://reactjs.org/), [Material](https://next.material-ui.com/), [Formik](https://formik.org/), [formik-material-ui](https://github.com/stackworx/formik-material-ui).

I have included a select component as follow

```
import { Formik, Form, Field } from "formik";
import { TextField } from "formik-material-ui";
import MenuItem from "@mui/material/MenuItem";

<Field
    component={TextField}
    type="text"
    select={true}
    align="left"
    fullWidth
    size="small"
    margin="dense"
    variant="outlined"
    name="student"
    >
    <MenuItem value={10}>X</MenuItem>
    <MenuItem value={15}>Y</MenuItem>
    <MenuItem value={20}>Z</MenuItem>
</Field>
```

But on selecting an input from the select dropdown, my Material-UI Appbar color is changing. I have attached the before and after screenshots below.

**Before:**
[image: Before]

**After:**
[image]

How to stop this from happening ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue resolved when I migrated `formik-material-ui` code locally to Material-Ui@v5.0.0 using the [migration-guide](https://next.material-ui.com/guides/migration-v4/) and imported the lib locally directly in my project.

Apparently using Material UI v4 and v5 together was the issue.